# autocomplete using wordpress SQL

Tags: wordpress

am trying autocomplete using wordpress database. i need specific value from meta_key in wordpress sql 
eg i need to fetch the location from meta_key but its shows all the values in meta_key

`

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'realnew';

//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

//get search term    
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY meta_key ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['meta_key'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search for meta values than why are you querying meta_key? Probably your meta key is something like "location" so you probably need something like this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'location' AND 'meta_value' LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY meta_key ASC");
```

Comment: What is your code on the front end? This will get you all the values but actually you need to pass them to javascript array and then you start inputting into the input field you need to filter that array of values and provide the first match as possible autocomplete values. Alternatively you could use something like seletc2 dropdown and pass all those values to it's options and enable filtering when user is entering a value.